# Not output of the array value when used scanner

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

**Below is the code. After entering the array, the console just goes blank and does not further output the array:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class advancedArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Provide us the size of the array:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = scanner.nextInt();

        int i = 0;
        int[] array = new int[value];

        System.out.println("Enter the array:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(input.hasNextInt()) {
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println("Array entered:");
        for(i=0;i<value;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
        input.close();
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Provide us the size of the array:
5
Enter the array:
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I'd strongly assume that due to `while(input.hasNextInt())` the application is waiting for the 6th int. Since you let the user input the array size anyways, why don't you loop just as many times? You'd have to take care of any input the user enters that is not an int but I consider handling that out of scope for now.

Comment: Don't create multiple scanners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are stuck in the "***reading the array***" part because of this

```
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        array[i] = input.nextInt();
```

hint: you know the size of the array, then why don't you do a for loop same as you did for printing out the array's content?? like:

```
for (int j = 0; j < value; j++) {
    array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with the `while` loop that you keep it waiting for more integers, it is better to convert to a normal for loop with condition on the entered array size `value`.

Also there is no need to use two `scanner` objects

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Provide us the size of the array:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int value = scanner.nextInt();

    int i = 0;
    int[] array = new int[value];

    System.out.println("Enter the array:");

    for (int j = 0; j < value; j++) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Array entered:");
    for (i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package Main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class advancedArrays {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Provide us the size of the array:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int value = scanner.nextInt();

    int i = 0;
    int[] array = new int[value];

    System.out.println("Enter the array:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(input.hasNextInt()) {
        array[i] = input.nextInt();
        i++;

        //Changed Code
        if (i == value) {
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Array entered:");
    for(i=0;i<value;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
    input.close();
    scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Fixed code, you were stuck reading your inputs for your array because you never checked if your inputs were the length of your array.

Fixed code.

```
if (i == value) {
    break;
}
```